# Tridion Delivery API/DD4T,How it connects internally to the Broker DB?

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t

While working on performance fixes I observed that one of the major function calls happen to broker Database while using dynamic components.
How API is connecting to Broker DB? Is it using Credentials provided in Cd_staorage_config or it connects internally to any delivery service which will talk to the broker Database?
what are the best practices we need to follow while working with Dynamic Components?
Do we have any documentation in SDL live content which explains about Broker Database connectivity using API?

Thanks,
Prasanna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prasanna,

Yes, the API uses the credentials provided in the cd_storage_conf.xml file.

The full API (chm files for .net) can be downloaded here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF

To understand how the Content Delivery side can be implemented have a look here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-91BEBD21-B99B-4E95-8F83-01B3909D4751